# Robolectric includeAndroidResources not found

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm following this http://robolectric.org/getting-started/

but I'm getting: 
Error:(61, 0) Could not set unknown property 'includeAndroidResources' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions$UnitTestOptions.

when I add

```
    android {
      testOptions {
        unitTests {
          includeAndroidResources = true
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of **includeAndroidResources**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Enables unit tests to use Android resources, assets, and manifests.

Answer (score 4):

starting with Robolectric 3.3 you’ll need Android Studio 3.0 alpha 5.

I guess you're using an older version of Android Studio.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2007.2 (latest version) and I see the same issue

Comment: Also, what does this mean for CI builds? Obviously it should be possible to run tests from command line?

Comment: I reported my problem here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3295

Comment: I get an error: **Could not set unknown property 'includeAndroidResources' for task ':app:testProductionDebugUnitTest' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidUnitTest. Open File**

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
          isIncludeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Including this:

```
android {

    testOptions.unitTests.isIncludeAndroidResources = true

 }
```

worked for me.